# Empty FileUpload Text Programmatically

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm using AJAX functionality to submit a form which contains a FileUpload control.

How can I reset the FileUpload (ie. remove the File listed) in code?

I do the same thing for a TextBox, which obviously has as easier way to set it back to the default...

```
TextBox.Text = "";
```

But The FileUpload doesn't have a similar option.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An article at - [value-ASP-NET-FileUpload-Control.aspx](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/2768-clear-value-ASP-NET-FileUpload-Control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won't allow JavaScript to tell the form whatever a type=File field will contain. It can only be changed by the user.